# How do I support “Tables” in Couchbase?

Tags: couchbase

RDBMSes have tables; also, similar concepts exist in NoSQL, like Kinds in Google Datastore. But Couchbase  puts everything into one big namespace. How do I arrange my data in a table-like way?

I want the performance advantages of table-like namespacing. If I have 1,000,000 rows of one type, and 10 rows of another, I'd rather that the query engine not have to look through 1,000,010 rows to find one of those ten.

- Buckets are available, but only up to ten. So, these are not really table-like.
- Tables could be implemented on the application layer with a `type` or `kind` property in each `JsonDocument`. But this mixes different abstraction layers: metadata with data.
- You can prefix each key with a "Table"-like  name. `"User:111"` instead of `111`.

How can I achieve the benefits of Tables/Kinds in Couchbase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, the correct way to do this is to add an attribute which represents the type of the document, and then create indexes with your "type" attribute in it. So your query will scan directly the index instead of a full table scan. This might sound uncommon at first, but indexes are one of the most powerful features in CB.

You can see if your query is using the index you have created in the "Plan" tab of the web console:
https://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-5-5-enhanced-query-plan-visualization/

If you are using Spring Data, it is done automatically or you through the attribute "_class" https://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-spring-boot-spring-data/

Creating multiple buckets for this use case isn't a good strategy, as you will need some extra work whenever you need to make a join.

There are some metadata about the document which you can access via meta() in your query (ex: meta().id, meta().cas) but the type itself has to stay as a top-level attribute of the document.

You can prefix each key with a "Table"-like name. "User:111" instead of 111. -> This is useful when you need to filter wich documents should be replicated via Cross Data Center Replication https://blog.couchbase.com/deep-dive-cross-data-center-replication-xdcr/